# my.cnf configuration in mysql 5.6.X

Tags: mysql, mysql5, my.cnf

Server information
64GB RAM

Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3930K CPU @ 3.20GHz

Mysql Server version: 5.6.20-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

I have 20 websites on this server like share hosting
my big site has MyIsAM table

Help me to configure this Mysql please

this is my default my.cnf

```
    # Example MySQL config file for very large systems.
#
# This is for a large system with memory of 1G-2G where the system runs mainly
# MySQL.
#
# MySQL programs look for option files in a set of
# locations which depend on the deployment platform.
# You can copy this option file to one of those
# locations. For information about these locations, see:
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/option-files.html
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
# with the "--help" option.

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
#password   = your_password
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
local-infile = 0
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 384M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 512
sort_buffer_size = 2M
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_size = 32M
# Try number of CPU's*2 for thread_concurrency
thread_concurrency = 12

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
# 
#skip-networking

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
log-bin=mysql-bin

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id   = 1

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)
#
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
# two methods :
#
# 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
#    the syntax is:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
#
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
#
#    Example:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
#
# OR
#
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
#
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
# (and different from the master)
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set
# but will not function as a slave if omitted
#server-id       = 2
#
# The replication master for this slave - required
#master-host     =   <hostname>
#
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
# to the master - required
#master-user     =   <username>
#
# The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
# the master - required
#master-password =   <password>
#
# The port the master is listening on.
# optional - defaults to 3306
#master-port     =  <port>
#
# binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
#log-bin=mysql-bin
#
# binary logging format - mixed recommended 
#binlog_format=mixed

# Uncomment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#innodb_data_home_dir = /var/lib/mysql
#innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:2000M;ibdata2:10M:autoextend
#innodb_log_group_home_dir = /var/lib/mysql
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
#innodb_buffer_pool_size = 384M
#innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 20M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
#innodb_log_file_size = 100M
#innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
#innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 256M
sort_buffer_size = 256M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

More information :
I want to use my 64Gb Ram , my mysql load is high , websites load slow.

Comment: What is the exact problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: mysql load is high , and web sites are slow . 64GB ram should help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to ensure that at least indices of your DBs are fit into the cache. Also it is good idea to make `join` and `sort` buffers big enough to prevent on-disk temporary tables creation.

My config for 32GB RAM is looks like that:

```
. . . . .
[mysqld]
. . . . .
  max_connections               = 64
  thread_cache_size             = 8
  thread_concurrency            = 8

  key_buffer_size               = 4G
  max_heap_table_size           = 128M

  join_buffer_size              = 32M
  sort_buffer_size              = 32M
  read_buffer_size              = 32M
  read_rnd_buffer_size          = 32M
  myisam_sort_buffer_size       = 32M

  query_cache_limit             = 32M
  query_cache_size              = 64M
  table_open_cache              = 64
  max_allowed_packet            = 1M
. . . . .
```

Keep in mind that `key_buffer` is used by all threads cooperatively while `join_buffer` and `sort_buffer` are created by each thread for private use, so max amount of used RAM is calculated as `join|sort_buffer_size` * `max_connections`.

Sure RAM consumption depends on the DB's structure and queries. Probably your best values would be different from mine.

There is a very useful tool called `mysqltuner` that gives alot of reasonable stats for tuning:

```
-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 6s (9 q [1.500 qps], 6 conn, TX: 14K, RX: 481)
[--] Reads / Writes: 100% / 0%
[--] Total buffers: 4.2G global + 128.3M per thread (64 max threads)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 12.2G (38% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/9)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 1% (1/64)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 4.0G/2.9G
[!!] Query cache efficiency: 0.0% (0 cached / 4 selects)
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 0% (0 on disk / 2 total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 83% (1 created / 6 connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 100% (26 open / 0 opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (21/939K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (36 immediate / 36 locks)
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 128.0M/336.0K
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0
```

that stat above is from the freshly restarted mysql-server so values are partly irrelevant.

Comment: thank you , mysqltuner is not compatible with mysql 5.6

Comment: `mysqltuner` gives advices not applicable to 5.6 but metrics are still valid. In fact all you need is the RAM-calculations and cache rates. Give to mysql about half of RAM and be sure that `key buffer size` is twice as big as `total MyISAM indexes`.